# Angular 8 - Mat-Chip should only set value of chip data

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

My mat-chip works pretty well for the most part. It set all chip data to my form control values. However if I typed-in something then undo/backspaced the words in the input box without adding it to chip, it sends the empty string only and totally ignoring all the chip values. Here's my code:

Component.html

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="label">
    <mat-label><b>Fruits</b></mat-label>
    <mat-chip-list #chipList aria-label="Fruit selection">
        <mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of fruits; let indx=index;"
             [selectable]="selectable"
             [removable]="removable"
             (removed)="remove(fruit, indx)">
                 {{fruit}}
             <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
        </mat-chip>
        <input
             placeholder="Add Fruits"
             #fruitInput
             formControlName="fruitControl"
             [matAutocomplete]="auto"
             [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
             [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
             [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
             (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
    </mat-chip-list>
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of filteredFruits | async [value]="fruit.name">
            {{fruit.name}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

component.ts (add chip function)

```
  add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    if (!this.matAutocomplete.isOpen) {
      const input = event.input;
      const value = event.value;

      // Add our fruit
      if ((value || '').trim() && this.fruits.length < 2) {
        this.fruits.push(value.trim());
        input.value = '';
      }


      // Reset the input value
      if (input) {
        // input.value = '';
        this.form.controls.fruitControl.setValue(this.fruits);
      }


      if(this.fruits.length > 2) {
        this.chipList.errorState = true;
      }

      this.form.controls.fruitControl.setValue(this.fruits);
    }
  }


  remove(fruit, indx): void {
    this.fruits.splice(indx, 1);

    if(this.fruits.length <= 2) {
      this.chipList.errorState = false;
    }
  }


  selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
    if (this.fruits.length < 2) {
      this.fruits.push(event.option.viewValue);
      this.fruitInput.nativeElement.value = '';
    }
  }
```

component.ts(subscribe & autocomplete function)

```
 getFruits(): void {
     this.service_.getAllFruits().subscribe(
     res => {
       this.fruitList = res;
      });

    this.filteredFruit = this.form.controls.fruitControl.valueChanges
     .pipe(
     startWith(''),
     map(name => name ? this._filters(name) : this.fruitList.slice())
    );
  }

    private _filters(value: any): any[] {
     return this.fruitList.filter(fruit => fruit.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) === 0 && !this.fruits.find( existingFruit => existingFruit === fruit ));
  }
```

Update with stackblitz sample:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nzjugg?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Try entering value with chip then another value without clicking enter where you later backspaced/cancel the typing. You can see in the console that its push empty string instead of chip values to the form.

Comment: can u make a sample in stackblitz.com , and provide the link?

Comment: @NibinBaby https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqnqku?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html  its my first time using stackblitz. Hope its the right link. You can see the result in the console log

Comment: in the code , change in add method 
      this.fruitCtrl.setValue(this.fruits); to
      this.fruitCtrl.setValue(null); , just like in this
https://stackblitz.com/angular/xorelylakej?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchips-autocomplete-example.ts

Comment: @NibinBaby that would returns null value when I submit though. I set the form control value to this.fruits so that its submitted to form. I guess its has something to do with form control capturing the entire input field instead of the chip where it is manually set with setValue but i am not sure how to approach it

Comment: just take the this.filteredFruits for submission, it contains the selected items as an array